# Uplay Shop Tab Missing

Tags: pc, ubisoft-connect

I'm in a very strange situation. When I run Uplay and log in, there is no shop tab. Usually, I start all my PC games from Steam, which means I don't use Uplay very often.

I tried to fix this bug by reinstalling the latest version of Uplay, but this didn't help. I always log in online; I never use offline mode.

Did I miss a special setting to enable the shop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post in the Ubisoft forums](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1336404-Shop-Tab-vs-No-Shop-Tab-Forums), you can't see the shop if:

1. > Uplay account only has games purchased via Steam
2. > You launch Uplay via Steam

But you can see the shop if:

> You launch Uplay from its own shortcut and own at least one game that you 
>   didn't buy through Steam.

**What you can do:**

> You can still buy games from http://shop.ubi.com/ regardless of if you
>   can see the shop tab in the client or not. If you decided to do that
>   at some point (Or anywhere else other than Steam) then you'd be able
>   to see the shop by simply launching Uplay from its own shortcut in
>   future.

Answer (score 4):

Found this answer made by community manager at [Uplay's forum](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/995476-Uplay-shop-missing-Forums)

> Hello, you will not see the Shop tab if you launch Uplay from a Steam
>   game or only have games owned through Steam on your Uplay account.

Comment: Okay. But now I want to purchase a game directly in Uplay. How am I gonna do this?

Comment: You can still buy from their website as @Denelio said and sending a ticket to them would be a good idea, maybe they see that this policy is a bit counter productive. Also, could you accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround you can do is actually by clicking "Quit" in UPlay's client, then launching it again (not through Steam). You will be able to use all of UPlay's functions.

Comment: No even if you launch it outside of steam (via clicking the uplay shortcut icon), you will not get a store tab...you have to have a game through ubisoft for it to show up

Answer (score 1):

You can also start C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubisoft\Ubisoft Game Launcher.
It launches with all the functions.