# Why can't I buy any games in Uplay after linking Steam account?

Tags: steam, pc, ubisoft-connect

After buying a Ubisoft game on Steam, the store in the Uplay launcher disappeared.

Comment: In that case I think [this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/299011/uplay-shop-tab-missing) is a duplicate. Can you check the answer there to see if that's correct?

Comment: its similar but that helped to thx

Answer (score 1):

I had to learn this myself also, apparently if you **ONLY** have Steam games on your Uplay account, the UPlay client expects you to only play said games, and thus, only pruchasing games through Steam. It's an easy fix though.

Go to https://store.ubi.com/ and login, here you can purchase new titles. When you first buy a title here, it'll unlock your account and you can access things like the store through the client.

Comment: i already had r6s that i bought through uplay

Comment: after buying uno through steam the store icon disapeared in the uplay launcher

Comment: but thanks i now know how o buy another game thanks